# How to get a better legend in ggpattern

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I want to represent two pieces of information in the polygons of a map: the group each one belongs to and the value of a variable.
For that I'm using ggplot with ggpattern.
However, the pattern legend is illegible, with a dark background.
Is there a way to improve the visibility of this legend?

[image: map]

Below is an example code.

The code to get the map with the grid step by step can be find [here](https://gist.github.com/aolinto/9ed2b579bd6e8bb1ad5d73c4acc6a93b).

Thanks

```
### libraries

library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)

### dataset

frt.area_data <-
structure(list(id = c("g1", "g1", "g1", "g1", "g1", "g10", "g10", 
"g10", "g10", "g10", "g11", "g11", "g11", "g11", "g11", "g12", 
"g12", "g12", "g12", "g12", "g13", "g13", "g13", "g13", "g13", 
"g14", "g14", "g14", "g14", "g14", "g15", "g15", "g15", "g15", 
"g15", "g16", "g16", "g16", "g16", "g16", "g2", "g2", "g2", "g2", 
"g2", "g3", "g3", "g3", "g3", "g3", "g4", "g4", "g4", "g4", "g4", 
"g5", "g5", "g5", "g5", "g5", "g6", "g6", "g6", "g6", "g6", "g7", 
"g7", "g7", "g7", "g7", "g8", "g8", "g8", "g8", "g8", "g9", "g9", 
"g9", "g9", "g9"), long = c(-47.23333333, -47.23333333, -47.06666667, 
-47.06666667, -47.23333333, -47.06666667, -47.06666667, -46.9, 
-46.9, -47.06666667, -46.9, -46.9, -46.73333333, -46.73333333, 
-46.9, -46.73333333, -46.73333333, -46.56666667, -46.56666667, 
-46.73333333, -47.23333333, -47.23333333, -47.06666667, -47.06666667, 
-47.23333333, -47.06666667, -47.06666667, -46.9, -46.9, -47.06666667, 
-46.9, -46.9, -46.73333333, -46.73333333, -46.9, -46.73333333, 
-46.73333333, -46.56666667, -46.56666667, -46.73333333, -47.06666667, 
-47.06666667, -46.9, -46.9, -47.06666667, -46.9, -46.9, -46.73333333, 
-46.73333333, -46.9, -46.73333333, -46.73333333, -46.56666667, 
-46.56666667, -46.73333333, -47.23333333, -47.23333333, -47.06666667, 
-47.06666667, -47.23333333, -47.06666667, -47.06666667, -46.9, 
-46.9, -47.06666667, -46.9, -46.9, -46.73333333, -46.73333333, 
-46.9, -46.73333333, -46.73333333, -46.56666667, -46.56666667, 
-46.73333333, -47.23333333, -47.23333333, -47.06666667, -47.06666667, 
-47.23333333), lat = c(-24.00000033, -23.83333367, -23.83333367, 
-24.00000033, -24.00000033, -24.33333367, -24.166667, -24.166667, 
-24.33333367, -24.33333367, -24.33333367, -24.166667, -24.166667, 
-24.33333367, -24.33333367, -24.33333367, -24.166667, -24.166667, 
-24.33333367, -24.33333367, -24.50000033, -24.33333367, -24.33333367, 
-24.50000033, -24.50000033, -24.50000033, -24.33333367, -24.33333367, 
-24.50000033, -24.50000033, -24.50000033, -24.33333367, -24.33333367, 
-24.50000033, -24.50000033, -24.50000033, -24.33333367, -24.33333367, 
-24.50000033, -24.50000033, -24.00000033, -23.83333367, -23.83333367, 
-24.00000033, -24.00000033, -24.00000033, -23.83333367, -23.83333367, 
-24.00000033, -24.00000033, -24.00000033, -23.83333367, -23.83333367, 
-24.00000033, -24.00000033, -24.166667, -24.00000033, -24.00000033, 
-24.166667, -24.166667, -24.166667, -24.00000033, -24.00000033, 
-24.166667, -24.166667, -24.166667, -24.00000033, -24.00000033, 
-24.166667, -24.166667, -24.166667, -24.00000033, -24.00000033, 
-24.166667, -24.166667, -24.33333367, -24.166667, -24.166667, 
-24.33333367, -24.33333367), order = 1:80, hole = c(FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), piece = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "1", class = "factor"), 
    group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
    11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
    14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 
    16L, 16L, 16L), .Label = c("g1.1", "g10.1", "g11.1", "g12.1", 
    "g13.1", "g14.1", "g15.1", "g16.1", "g2.1", "g3.1", "g4.1", 
    "g5.1", "g6.1", "g7.1", "g8.1", "g9.1"), class = "factor"), 
    GROUP = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
    "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "c", "c", 
    "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "d", 
    "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "d", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", 
    "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", 
    "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
    "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"), VALUE = c(2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 11, 11, 11, 
    11, 11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
    13, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 6, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6)), row.names = c(NA, -80L
), class = "data.frame")

### ggplot map

map <- ggplot(frt.area_data,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=id,fill=VALUE,map_id=id)) +
    geom_polygon() +
    coord_map() +
    theme_bw(12) +
    theme(legend.key.size = unit(1, 'cm')) +
    geom_map_pattern(
        map = frt.area_data,
        aes(
            pattern_type = GROUP,
        ),
        pattern              = 'magick',
        pattern_fill         = 'black',
        pattern_scale        = 1.5,
        pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.7,
        pattern_alpha        = 0.5,
        colour               = 'black',
#~      fill                 = 'white'
    ) +
    expand_limits(x = frt.area_data$long, y = frt.area_data$lat) +
    scale_pattern_type_discrete(choices = c(a='horizontal', b='left45', c='right45', d='vertical'))

map
```

Comment: One option would be adjust the values of the aesthetic used for the legend using `override.aes `, e.g. `scale_pattern_type_discrete..., guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "white"))` will switch the fill color used for the legend to "white".

Comment: It is hard to reproduce your plot because there are missing packages and errors

Comment: Thanks Stefan. This solved my problem! I had never use "override.aes". Also to fine tune the legend I had to play around with values for pattern_scale and pattern_key_scale_factor. Many thanks

Comment: @neuron the hardest part is to have ggpattern installed. I use Ubuntu 20.04.3 and R 4.1.2 Bird Hippie. First I had to install libmagick++-dev and libudunits2-dev to Linux. In R I had to install the package remotes and then install ggpattern with remotes::install_github("coolbutuseless/ggpattern").

Comment: @Antonio the problem I was encountering was during fortify

Comment: @neuron fortify is from maptools package. I edited the library section above.

Comment: @Antonio In the future, if you're having an issue with just a graph and not the actual code to generate the data you want to graph, just use `dput()` and post the output in your question. I still can't get fortify to run but all I really need is the data rather than the code you used to generate the data.

Comment: @neuron thanks for your recommendation. I've edited my post to meet your suggestion.